# Two different solutions of $\int\frac{1}{1+x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am having doubt in the calculation of the integral
$$
\int\frac{1}{1+x} \ dx,$$

the solution of which is
$$
\log(1+x)+C.$$

I have solved this integration in a different way. First I converted the above integral to
$$
\;\int\frac{1}{1+(\sqrt{x})^2} \ dx.$$
Then I used the formula as 
$$
{\int\frac{1}{1+x^2} dx}=\tan^{-1}x+C
$$
so by using this formula I got as an answer  $\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{x})+C$ which is different from the solution.

Am I correct about this?

Comment: Differentiating $\tan^{-1}\sqrt x$ gives $\frac1{2\sqrt x(1+x)}$.

Comment: The correct answer is $\ln(|1+x|)+C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution $x=t^2$ (which, by the way, can be done only for $x\ge0$) brings the integral in the form
$$
\int\frac{1}{1+t^2}\cdot 2t\,dt=\log(1+t^2)+c=\log(1+x)+c
$$

Recall that integration by substitution is an application of the chain rule for derivatives. The $dx$ is a reminder for you to apply it (more than that, actually).

Otherwise you'd get, similarly to your manipulation,
$$
\int x\,dx=\int (\sqrt{x})^2\,dx=\frac{(\sqrt{x})^3}{3}+c
$$
which is clearly absurd. Or
$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\sqrt{x})^2}}\,dx=\arcsin\sqrt{x}+c
$$
whereas the correct antiderivative is $-2\sqrt{1-x}+c$.

Answer (score 10):

No. You forgot to change $\rm{d}x$ into $\rm{d}(\sqrt x)$.